# How to use your own tokens in other contracts?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

so I created a token tokenA

```
contract tokenA is ERC20 {
    address public deployer; //to save adress of the deployer
    
    constructor() ERC20('tokenA', 'TA') { //called by the deployer (once)
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000000 * 10 ** 10); //mint/create tokens - we have created 100000000000*10^18 tokens
        deployer = msg.sender;  //set the deployer
    }

    //total supply is fixed no more can be created ever

    function burn (uint amount) external {  //remove tokens by sending then to a zero address
        _burn(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

and I have deployed them onto the Rinkeby (4) injected web3 environment.
now I have to use these tokens as price for purchasing an NFT (which I also have to make)

so how do I use them in my code?

I can use ether like

uint price = 0.005 ether;

and the compare the transferred value with this, but if I write

uint price = 0.005 tokenA;

it gives an error, even though I have deployed tokenA and it resides in my meta mask acc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uint price = 0.005 ether;` this is correct.
But inside your function to buy an NFT you need:

1. Remove the `payable` keyword.
2. Add the `transferFrom` function of the ERC-20 token in order to transfer `price` (0.005e18) tokens to the recipient address you specify.

Keep in mind that in order to successfully call the `transferFrom` function the user first need to call the `approve` function.

For a more in dept explanation i suggest to read the OpenZeppelin ERC-20 docs/github repo

Comment: I understand that, I just need to know how to use the token i deployed, tokenA as a price, instead of ether

Comment: I know how to use ether as price, I need to know how can a user send 5 tokenA's to purchase an NFT

Comment: `uint price = 0.005 ether` doesn't mean that the price is 0.005 ETH (15.15$).

Comment: In order to send 5 tokenA you just call `tokenA.transferFrom(msg.sender, <your-address>, 5 ether)`

Comment: ah I see, what if there is a choice like the user can pay through ether or tokenA how would the logic playout, you don't have to code it for me, just a laymen explanation will be enough (English is my second language)

Comment: Create two functions, `buyWithToken` and `buyWithEth` with different payment logic

Comment: ah I see I can do that! just a little problem while writing tokenA.transfer(msg.sender, owner, 5); it says expected an identifier but got a '(' what am i missing?

Comment: You should paste the code here

Comment: address owner;
    tokenA t;
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    } 
    function paywithplt() public {
        t.transfer(owner, 1);
    }

Comment: this is a test code to see if my tokens are transferring,  they always produce a 'Gas estimation failed' error message

Comment: You need to use `transferFrom`, not `transfer`

Comment: sadly, same error

Comment: Yes, because the user first need to call the approve function and approve the transfer of X tokens to the owner

Comment: but the user already has these token in their wallet, that's why I used transfer method

Comment: Ok but that isn't enough. You should check out OpenZeppelin docs on the ERC-20 standard

Comment: alright, is there any think in particular i should look out for, because i have read that document multiple time